# How to create MS access table structure in a MS SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, ms-access

I need to create the existing MS Access table structure in a MS SQL server database using C#.

I know there are some tools that can be achieve this. but I need to do this programmatically.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Yes, there are many ways this can be done. What have you tried so far?

Comment: I tried to search some C# API to do so. but couldn't find. can you guide me to some msdn document or article?

Comment: Simple Google search provides: [How to load an Access Database into a DataSet object in C#](http://sizious.com/2015/05/11/how-to-load-an-access-database-into-a-dataset-object-in-c/), [Table.Create Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.table.create.aspx)

Comment: @ChrisPickford: That's on another topic.

Comment: This site doesn't exist for people to write code for you, you'll need to put your own work in.